# How insert date from cell to google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my script is date start and end date for example: ("August 01, 2019" start date) and ("August 30, 2019" end date) And I want to read cell data to make it easy to change.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("for_example@gmail.com");
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date ("August 01, 2019"), new Date("August 30, 2019"));
```

Can I load somehow date from cell? Start date will in cell "A1" and end date in "B1"

Final state:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("for_example@gmail.com");
      var events = cal.getEvents(new Date ("A1"), new Date("B1"));// this is problem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the contents in your cell are formatted as dates, you can get them simply with `get.Value()` :

```
  var events = cal.getEvents(ss.getRange("A1").getValue(), ss.getRange("B1").getValue());
```

Comment: Thank you but it still gives me an error: 'Can't find getEvents (string, string)' Can you help me? I generate from sheet 1 and create another sheet, could it be?

Comment: It sounds like your parameters are strings (while they are supposed to be dates). Can you please log the contents of cells `A1` and `A2` with  Logger.log(ss.getRange("A1").getValue())  and  Logger.log(ss.getRange("A2").getValue()) and see the output?

Comment: Thank you, I am not loading from the first page who I wanted to add var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet (). GetSheetByName ("Sheet 1"); Now it works correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ss.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue()
```

to get the value from the spreadsheet cell.